# Difference of Poisson r.v's. Is there a simpler way?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here's a problem I'm having trouble with (section on Poisson r.v.'s):

Suppose that when a baby is born, the probability it's a boy is $0,52$ and the probability that it's a girl is $0,48$. On some day, 100 babies were born in a hospital. What's the probability that more girls were born? Here's my attempt:

---

Let $B$ be the amount of boys born, and $G$ the amount of girls. We want to find $P(G-B>0)$. The two r.v.s are Poisson distributed: $G \sim Poiss(48), B \sim Poiss(52)$. This would mean having to find the distribution of $G-B$, the difference of two Poisson r.v's with different parameters - according to Wikipedia that's something called a Skellam distribution, and it looks complicated, which makes me think that there's probably a simpler way. But I don't know how to do it. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ and $b$ be the parameters for the $G$ and $B$ distributed as Poisson. Since you know that there are $100$ babies born, you can use conditioning as follows:

$P(G > B)=\sum_{k=0}^{49} [P(B=k) | P(G+B=100)]$

Now,

\begin{align*}
 P(B=k) | P(G+B=100)&=\frac{P(B=k)*P(G=100-k)}{P(G+B=100}) \\
 &=\frac{\frac{e^{-b}b^{k}e^{-g}g^{100-k}}{k!(100-k)!}}{\frac{e^{-(b+g)}(b+g)^{100}}{100!}} 
\end{align*}

The above can be simplified to a Binomial distribution  $ \sim \operatorname{B} \left({100,\frac{b}{b+g}}\right)$

So in essence you need to calculate:

$\sum_{k=0}^{49} \operatorname{B} \left({100,\frac{b}{b+g}}\right)$ which is equivalent to calculating the CDF of the binomial distribution. You can lookup the calculations involving Binomial CDFs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function).